# If $I$ is a closed ideal in a C*-algebra $A$ and $J$ is a closed ideal in $I$ then $J$ is an ideal of $A$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

The following is a remark of Murphy's C*-algebras and operator theory:

[image].

I do not know why he uses approximate unit. I think for $a\in A$ and $b\in J^+$, we have $b\in I$  and $b^{1/2}\in I$($I$ is a C*-algebra)so $ab^{1/2}\in I$ and $J$ is an ideal of $I$, thus $ab=(ab^{1/2})b^{1/2}\in J$. Where is my mistake? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your proof. Yes, for all $b \in J^+$ we also have $b \in I$ and therefore $ab,ba \in I$. But it doesn't follow that $ab^{1/2}$ or $ab$ are in $J$.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer:   $b\in I$, and also $b^{1/2}\in I$. for $a\in A$, $ab^{1/2}\in I$, and J is an ideal of $I$ so $ab =(ab^{1/2})b^{1/2}\in J$

Comment: How does $ab \in J$ follow from $ab^{1/2}\in I$? We have $b \in J^+$ but as far as I can tell there is no reason why we should also have $b^{1/2}$.

Comment: @RudytheReindeer: if you read Murphy's paragraph carefully, he himself says that $b^{1/2}\in J$. Which is obvious, since $J$ is a C$^*$-algebra.

Answer (score 2):

I think your argument is fine. I fail to see why Murphy feels the need to use approximate units in this argument.

Comment: I think approximate units can be used in this way:
$$\left. \begin{align*}&b=\lim u_\lambda b \Rightarrow ab=\lim au_\lambda b\\
& au_\lambda\in I\Rightarrow au_\lambda b\in J\end{align*}\right\}\Rightarrow ab\in J.$$ While we do not need to wirte $b$ as $b^\frac{1}{2}b^\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Yes, I see nothing wrong with that.